# Verify that $f $ is constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $K(x) = x$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend period to real space.

Suppose $f \in L^2[-1,1]$ satisfies $\int_{-1}^{1} K(x-t)f(t) dt = 0$ for any $x$. Then, $f$ is a constant function.

I have no idea for this problem.

Comment: How much Fourier analysis do you know?

Comment: In fact, we will construct an orthogonal basis on $L^1[-1,1]$ by this problem.

Comment: Do you know, what is convolution?

Comment: yes. It is OK. Except the basis of $L^1$, because it is goal

Comment: Extend $f$ periodically to all $\mathbb{R}$ and take the Fourier transform of the condition $K \ast f = 0$. What does that say?

Comment: Get $\hat{K}(x)\hat{f}(x) = 0$.

Comment: Next step is explain $\hat{f}$ is delta function?